# Drawing arc cocos2d-html5

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

I'm trying to draw arc on cocos2d-html5, but cant find function to use. DrawSegment used parameters point,point,radius,color. But radius - width of line, not arc. What can I use to draw arc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we should add the function to cocos2d-html5

Thanks for feedback.

This function has been created at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/3767